# Accessing a JSON object based on one key-value

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have incoming json objects. What i want to do is to filter the JSON based on its key. For example I have three incoming json objects.

```
Sending message: {"deviceId":"test","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":398}

Sending message: {"deviceId":"temp","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":399}

Sending message: {"deviceId":"temp","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":400}

Sending message: {"deviceId":"test","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":01}

Sending message: {"deviceId":"temp","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":402}
```

I want only those json objects where deviceid is test and not temp. I am trying to filter the JSON. How can i do this?

Comment: is it coming in form of array of objects? if not push those object in ana array and then filter in array using arry filter prototype

Comment: parse the JSON **strings** to javascript **objects** first ... then use the javascript object like any other i.e. check for `obj.deviceId == 'test'` - in this case, the JSON string was parsed to an object called `obj`

Comment: What code have you tried so far? The method of filtering will be different depending on how the json is coming in to the script.

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, now after i apply this condition, how do i return or print the whole json object based on that  value 'test' ?

Comment: I don't know, because your code is lacking

Comment: @wmorrell I'm using `JSON.stringify` for the incoming strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write you an example

say you have list of

```
let obj = {
    "deviceId":"test",
    "temperature":11,
    "latitude":50,
    "longitude":19,
    "time":1,
    "id":398
}
```

Then you can selecte `deviceId` by `obj['deviceId']`

```
for (let index in listOfObj){

    let curObj = listOfObj[index];

    if(curObj['deviceId'] === 'test'){
        //Do whatever you want with the object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a basic example which describes how you can check whether the `deviceId` is 'test' or 'temp' and based on that you can run a loop on the object keys and apply whatever logic you want to apply on it.

Hope this helps.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(e){
var obj = {
    "deviceId":"test",
    "temperature":11,
    "latitude":50,
    "longitude":19,
    "time":1,
    "id":398
}
if(obj["deviceId"]==="test"){
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(e){
  alert(e+" "+obj[e]);
})
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com) library.

```
var messages = [{msg1}, {msg2}];
var filteredMessages = _.filter(messages, {deviceId: "test"});
// filteredMessages is an Array of messages with deviceId equals to `test`
```

Comment: why use a library when native javascript Array's already have a filter method

Comment: it's because Lodash(or Underscore) is very useful to manipulate data objects in javascript, especially for new learners

Comment: native javascript is also very useful to manipulate data objects in javascript, ESPECIALLY for new learners

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your objects are in an array, you can achieve this using the native Javascript [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method,

```
var arr = [
    {"deviceId":"test","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":398},
    {"deviceId":"temp","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":399},
    {"deviceId":"temp","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":400},
    {"deviceId":"test","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":01},
    {"deviceId":"temp","temperature":11,"latitude":50,"longitude":19,"time":1,"id":402}
];

var results = arr.filter(function(obj) {
    // Return true to keep the element
    return obj.deviceId === "test";
});

console.log(results);
```